# ASDoc through the Flex Builder UI?

Tags: apache-flex, flexbuilder, asdoc

Is there any way to run ASDoc on your project via the Flex Builder UI?  Or, is there a good (preferably free) plugin that will do so?

If there is no UI for it, does someone have a link to a tutorial on how to set it up to be automatic when I build my project, maybe via Ant (which I've never used, but am more than happy to try) or something?
(sorry for the multi-part question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some links to ant tasks that run AsDoc for you:

- [one from Eric Feminella](http://www.ericfeminella.com/blog/2007/06/07/asdocanttask-project-for-eclipse/)
- [one from Christophe Herreman](http://www.herrodius.com/blog/85)

Answer (score 2):

The solution at Seb Lee-Delisle's blog worked pretty well for me! I recommend it to anyone who is still looking for a solution. To get it working for me I had to use "Browse Workspace.." to add the specific project folder rather than use `${project_loc}` as suggested for current project. Also wrap the path to your swc folder in quotes for -library-path if you have spaces in any of the directory names. Escaping the spaces in the Arguments field did not seem to work for me.

http://sebleedelisle.com/2009/03/how-to-set-up-asdoc-in-flex-builder/

If this is outdated in anyway or anyone has any bits to add it would be nice to hear them. I have not seen this explanation anywhere else yet so it was quite nice to find it worked :)

Answer (score 1):

[This tool](http://www.idefactory.com/) says it does that in a single click on the features page, although it may be a bit more than you are looking for.

Comment: Looks like a promising set of extra tools.  I'll be keeping an eye on that.

Answer (score 1):

You can define a launch configuration in the external tools that will run the asdoc utility.

Details are provided in this blog post [Launching ASDoc with External Tools](http://amiest-devblog.blogspot.com/2007/12/launching-asdoc-with-external-tools.html) @amieStreetDevelopment

Another one: [AsDoc with Eclipse](http://blog.formatlos.de/2008/07/10/asdoc-with-eclipse/) @formatlos

Answer (score 1):

SourceMate also provides this feature.  You can download a free 30 day trial at:

[www.elementriver.com/sourcemate](http://www.elementriver.com/sourcemate)

SourceMate also offers many more features for Flex development too.